# Map key value pair in java not getting properly

Tags: java, dictionary

i am  using Map for inserting some objects, while puting object its working fine ,
 but while iterating same map i m getting the size of object as correctly, but  i m gettting only 
last object,in all the iteration , for ur reference i am pasting all the code as follows,

```
package map;

    Map<Integer,ListLabcar> ma = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ListLabcar>();
    ListLabcar lc = new ListLabcar();
    for(int l =0;l<5;l++){
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<=3;i++){
            if(i==l){
                System.out.println("ok");
                j+=1;
                lc.setIn(j);
                lc.setS("a-"+l);break;
            }
            else{
                lc.setIn(l);
                lc.setS("zero-"+l);
                //break;
            }
        }
        ma.put(l, lc);
        System.out.println(ma.get(l).getIn());
        System.out.println(ma.get(l).getS());
    }System.out.println(ma.size());
    Set<Integer> ke = ma.keySet();
    for(Integer k:ke){
        System.out.println(k);
        System.out.println("int--->"+ma.get(k).getIn());
        System.out.println("sttr--->"+ma.get(k).getS());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: my ListLabcar.java as package map;

public class ListLabcar {
 private Integer in;
 private String s;
 public Integer getIn() {
  return in;
 }
 public void setIn(Integer in) {
  this.in = in;
 }
 public String getS() {
  return s;
 }
 public void setS(String s) {
  this.s = s;
 }

}

Comment: my output is ok
1
a-0
ok
1
a-1
ok
1
a-2
ok
1
a-3
4
zero-4
5
0
int--->4
sttr--->zero-4
1
int--->4
sttr--->zero-4
2
int--->4
sttr--->zero-4
3
int--->4
sttr--->zero-4
4
int--->4
sttr--->zero-4

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Instead, edit your question and add the information to it - properly formatted.

Comment: but i want my output like ok
1
a-0
1

a-1

1
a-2

1
a-3
4
zero-4

Comment: i tried i am new to this forum, i am not able to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line need to be in the first for loop.

```
ListLabcar lc = new ListLabcar();
```

What you are doing is rewriting the values and not adding new objects in the map.

EDIT :

```
package map;

    Map<Integer,ListLabcar> ma = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ListLabcar>();
    for(int l =0;l<5;l++){
        ListLabcar lc = new ListLabcar();
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<=3;i++){
            if(i==l){
                System.out.println("ok");
                j+=1;
                lc.setIn(j);
                lc.setS("a-"+l);break;
            }
            else{
                lc.setIn(l);
                lc.setS("zero-"+l);
                //break;
            }
        }
        ma.put(l, lc);
        System.out.println(ma.get(l).getIn());
        System.out.println(ma.get(l).getS());
    }
    System.out.println(ma.size());
    Set<Integer> ke = ma.keySet();
    for(Integer k:ke){
        System.out.println(k);
        System.out.println("int--->"+ma.get(k).getIn());
        System.out.println("sttr--->"+ma.get(k).getS());
    }
}
```